# How do I free this fish person from their cell?

Tags: momodora-reverie-under-moonlight

In the Subterranean Grave I encountered a room with two people in cells. One looked like a panda and the other looked like a blue fish person. I was able to free the panda by hitting a switch, but I can't find a way to free fish person.

How do I free the fish person from their cell?

[image: fish person in cage asks to be freed]

[image: map location]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to free this character. No matter what you do in the area, this character can't be freed.

Comment: This feels like bad game design.

Comment: One common saying in the community is that it teaches the player that no hero can save everyone. But the way the character says you must find a way to save them would indeed make anyone think there's a hidden system to save them.